Validating a Shopify Webhook
In Shopify, webhooks can be created for certain events that take place in the admin such as updating a product and they provide a note that says:

Your webhooks will be signed with
6574fb9832abafa73b29d30f6f200264b063669592b993b23369a2793a3db8e6

According to the Shopify docs for validating a webhook, it gives the following example:
app.post('/webhooks', express.text({type: '*/*'}), async (req, res) => {
  const {valid, topic, domain} = await shopify.webhooks.validate({
    rawBody: req.body, // is a string
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });

  if (!valid) {
    // This is not a valid request!
    res.send(400); // Bad Request
  }

  // Run my webhook-processing code here
});

If we don't want to use Shopify's library for this, and instead use a Netlify serverless function, node:crypto can be imported, and the request contains an x-shopify-hmac-sha256 header which has the following format.
'x-shopify-hmac-sha256': 'rgru9agBDpdwRFeKtp0+ez3PXj9yL7J0YMfsn8f0bBs='

import crypto from 'node:crypto'

export default async (req) => {
  const secret = '6574fb9832abafa73b29d30f6f200264b063669592b993b23369a2793a3db8e6'
  const shopifyHmac = req.headers.get('x-shopify-hmac-sha256')
}

How can we validate the webhook given the x-shopify-hmac-sha256 and secret?
This is the current implementation I am using and although it does work I am not sure if this is secure enough for a production grade application and whether or not the crypto.timingSafeEqual adds any realistic security.
import crypto from 'node:crypto'

export default async (req, context) => {
  // req.headers.get('x-shopify-hmac-sha256') === 'Xr0VLYgdBC2HSU6X4BB+6zBczDjFFFRCVfJ1nap72UU='

  const shopifyHmac = 'Xr0VLYgdBC2HSU6X4BB+6zBczDjFFFRCVfJ1nap72UU='
  const secret = '6574fa9832abafa73b29d30f6f200264b063669592b993b21369a2793a3db8d6'

  const requestBody = await req.text();
  const requestBuffer = Buffer.from(requestBody, 'utf8');

  const hmac = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', secret)
    .update(requestBuffer)
    .digest('base64');

    const isValid = crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(hmac, 'base64'), Buffer.from(shopifyHmac, 'base64'));

    console.log('isValid: ', isValid); // true
}


There are examples in the NodeJS documentation for determining an HMAC, e.g. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hmac. What exactly is the problem?

I found this example from cloudflare and I have read that precautions should be taken against timing attacks. I‘m not entirely sure where to even start implementing this

Can you post the corresponding req.body for your secret and your x-shopify-hmac-sha256 (or if not, completely new values for secret, x-shopify-hmac-sha256 and req.body)?

I just updated my OP, when the webhook is triggered it sends a payload of products and variants ect that is too long to post here. It's a large json payload and await req.text() just returns a string version. If I were to use await req.json() I would be given the following error: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array.
